# Add new bundle outside Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just found bundle of asp.net MVC is amazing. It help me compress all those javascript&css files.

However, I think adding all static files in BundleConfig.cs is hard. (I feel that to register all static files which are in diffrent modules, different pages when appliction start is not a good idea.)

For example, some people of my team want to develop a partial view. In that partial view, there are some static files: stac1.js, stac2.js, style1.css, style2.css.

I prefer a solution: Register those files in an independent file of that module/page.
When some one access that module/page, those static files will be compressed.

Is that solution existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you prefer that when some one access that module/page, those static files will be compressed. It's better to compress this files in Application_Start because Application_Start is launch one once for all users application. The compression will be exectued only once, if you execute compression for each access of page/module, the loading time will be longer for final user